# Take user image as argument, then send message with same image with Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Let's just get this started off with.

I've been looking around Google trying to find a guide on how to take images as arguments and then sending that same image with the message the user provided.

I'm making an announcement command.

Right now, my command only takes text as input, not files/images.

Here's my announce command:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "afv!announce",
  description: "announce something",
  execute(msg, args, bot) {
    if (msg.member.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === "Bot Perms")) {
      const prevmsg = msg;
      const text = args.join().replace(/,/g, " ");
      msg
        .reply(
          "Would you like to do `@here` :shushing_face: or `@everyone` :loudspeaker:?\nIf you would like to ping something else, react with :person_shrugging:. (you will have to ping it yourself, sorry)\n*react with :x: to cancel*"
        )
        .then((msg) => {
          const areusure = msg;
          msg
            .react("")
            .then(() => msg.react(""))
            .then(() => msg.react(""))
            .then(() => msg.react("❌"));

          const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return (
              ["", "", "", "❌"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
              user.id === prevmsg.author.id
            );
          };

          msg
            .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ["time"] })
            .then((collected) => {
              const reaction = collected.first();

              if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
                areusure.delete();
                prevmsg
                  .reply("<a:AFVloading:748218375909539923> Give me a sec...")
                  .then((msg) => {
                    bot.channels.cache
                      .get("696135322240548874")
                      .send("@here\n\n" + text);
                    msg.edit("<a:AFVdone:748218438551601233> Done!");
                  });
              } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
                areusure.delete();
                prevmsg
                  .reply("<a:AFVloading:748218375909539923> Give me a sec...")
                  .then((msg) => {
                    bot.channels.cache
                      .get("696135322240548874")
                      .send("@everyone\n\n" + text);
                    msg.edit("<a:AFVdone:748218438551601233> Done!");
                  });
              } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
                areusure.delete();
                prevmsg
                  .reply("<a:AFVloading:748218375909539923> Give me a sec...")
                  .then((msg) => {
                    bot.channels.cache
                      .get("696135322240548874")
                      .send(
                        "Important: https://afv.page.link/announcement\n\n" +
                          text
                      );
                    msg.edit("<a:AFVdone:748218438551601233> Done!");
                  });
              } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌") {
                areusure.delete();
                prevmsg.reply("Cancelled.");
              }
            })
            .catch((collected) => {
              msg.delete();
              prevmsg.reply("you didn't react with any of the emojis above.");
            });
        });
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Avatar

To use images you can use this function :

```js
message.author.displayAvatarURL(
 { dynamic: true } /* In case the user avatar is animated we make it dynamic*/
);
```

Then it will return a link you can use for an embed thumbnail or image. If you want to use it in an embed

```js
let link = message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true });
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setThumbnail(link);
```

## Use Image Links

If you want to use an image link you'll have to transform it into a discord attachement.

```js
const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
const attach = new Discord.Attachement(args.join(' '), 'image_name.png');
message.channel.send(attach);
```

Hope I helped you. If not you can still search in [the discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/) ^^

## Not sure where the image link is

If you don't really know where the image link is in the message content you can separate it (you already did with arguments) and use a forEach function :

```js
const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);

// a function to see if it's an url
function isvalidurl(string) {
 try {
  const a = new URL(string);
 } catch (err) {
  return false;
 }
 return true;
}
// check the function for each argument
args.forEach((a) => {
 if (isvalidurl(a)) link = a;
});

if (link) {
 // code
} else {
 // code
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer. I'm looking for the image attachment of a user. For example:
User: afv!announce Check out this cool studio! (attaches image)
Bot: in #announcements: Check out this cool studio! (same image)
I hope this cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

[`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) has a property called [`attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments), which contains all of the attachments in the message. (A image uploaded by the user is counted as an attachment, however, a URL to an image, is not.)

---

Here's an example:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.author.bot) return false;
 if (message.attachments.size == 0)
  return message.channel.send('No attachments in this message.');

 const AnnouncementChannel = new Discord.TextChannel(); // This shall be announcement channel / the channel you want to send the embed to.

 const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
 Embed.setTitle('Hey!');
 Embed.setDescription('This is an announcement.');
 Embed.setImage(message.attachments.first().url);

 AnnouncementChannel.send(Embed);
});
```